Admin utility classes?
I am dipping into creating a super basic dashboard widget for a theme I plan to re-use.
In order to style the interior of the dashboard widget, I was wondering if there were utility classes used in the Admin that I can repurpose for basic things like "flex-justify" or "flex-col," etc.

There aren't any documented anywhere AFAIK. The only way to find them is to inspect existing parts of the UI.
I like your approach though. Way too many people try to style and brand their plugin as if it's a totally separate application rather than trying to blend in with the Dashboard.
